# Search icon not working

Tags: javascript, search, button, icons

I'm trying to add a search button to a client website but it doesn't do anything.

Is my javascript correct or am I doing something wrong?

See in this link: https://fiddle.jshell.net/mdcnzfLw/

Comment: it seems to work just fine. what do you expect for it to do?

Comment: whats wrong in your code?

Comment: What do you want to do on `keyup` event?

Comment: Works fine for me. Did you mean to also add an onclick to the `#icon`?

Comment: @CharanCherry the button doesn't search for anything inside of the website and I don't know how to do it. Can you help me, please? It's quite urgent!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't have an event handler for the click event. While CSS makes the icon look clickable, it has no action behind it.

You want to add to your init function:

```
 document.getElementById('icon').addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

and then add:

```
  function handleClick() {
      alert('You clicked on search');
  }
```

Replace the `alert` with whatever the code is supposed to do.

Comment: It suppose to do what search buttons do. What can I add more to make it usefull?

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('icon').addEventListener('click', handleClick());`

You missed the function call in the EventListener.

Comment: After I add the function call, how can I make it work? I don't understand :(